# Command eslint --init not found, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, eslint, lint

entered that command into mac terminal set to directory containing javascript file and package.json file, and after installing node.js, and running

```
npm install -g eslint
```

but i still get

```
-bash: eslint: command not found
```

so why?

Comment: If you install a tool globally, it places it in a specific location. If that location is not in your `PATH` environment variable, the executable will not be automatically found.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I needed to enter:

```
sudo npm install -g eslint
```

due to permissions issue